# Coffeescript instance method encapsulation in an Object

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Say I have a Coffeescript class:

```
class Foo
  MyMethodsBar: () => "bar"
  MyMethodsBaz: () => "baz"
```

Is there any way to encapsulate methods like this (not working):

```
class Foo
  MyMethods:
    bar: () => "bar"
    baz: () => "baz"
```

So I can call:

```
f = new Foo()
f.MyMethods.bar()
```

The problem is that `this` (or `@`) is not the instance when I do this like a regular method.

I'm trying to do this for cleaner mixins/concerns.

Thanks,
Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible, unless you create `MyMethods` inside the constructor and bind `this` to the methods. At which point you pretty much loose the benefits of using a class.

That's because when you call a method via `f.MyMethods.bar()`, `this` will refer to `f.MyMethods`. To prevent that, you could bind `bar` to specific object beforehand. However, at the moment you are defining `bar`, the instance of `Foo` to which `this` should refer to (`f`) does not exist yet, so you can't bind it outside of the constructor.

You could call the method with `f.MyMethods.bar.call(f)`, but that's rather cumbersome.